# How to insert different type of element in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have a `class` that has a reference to another `class`. A student class has a variable that has a reference to module info. I want to insert  the `moduleId` into an array but the struct is made up of different types of objects and is of type `moduleRef`. I would like to get the `moduleId` which is of type string. How can I grab this moduleId element form `ModuleRef`.

```
class Student {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var modulesRefs: [ModuleRef]

    var fullName: String {
        return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, modulesRefs: [ModuleRef]) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.modulesRefs = modulesRefs
    }

    func addModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
        self.modulesRefs.insert(moduleId, at: 0)
    }

     func removeModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
        self.modulesRefs = self.modulesRefs.filter { $0.moduleId != moduleId }
    }
}

class ModuleRef {
    var moduleName: String
    var moduleId: String
    var moduleStartdate: Int

    init(moduleName: String, moduleId: String, moduleStartdate: Int) {
        self.moduleName = moduleName
        self.moduleId = moduleId
        self.moduleStartdate = moduleStartdate
    }
}
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'ModuleRef'

Comment: Can you pls show the insertion method too?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon `insert` is in `Swift's standard library`

Comment: You are calling `addModuleId` to insert new value?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon yes. Which is a string

Comment: what about `moduleName` & `moduleStartdate`, when you pass only `moduleId`, what's will be the value of that two variables?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I'm not using any of those at the moment

Comment: ok that can be `nil`, then? Because in `class` name "ModuleRef", you have made them compulsory

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I can probably change that

Comment: Yes, you can make it `nil` or you can just pass the default value like an empty string and 0 value, what do you say?

Comment: Check the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the values of Type `ModuleRef` into that array. So i may modify the functions as:

```
func addModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
        let module = ModuleRef(moduleName: "", moduleId: moduleId, moduleStartdate: 0)
        self.modulesRefs.insert(module, at: 0)
    }

    func removeModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
        modulesRefs.removeAll(where: { $0.moduleId == moduleId })
    }
```

---

NB: If you don't need `moduleName` & `moduleStartdate` all time, you can mark it as Optional.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have made `class ModuleRef { ... }` values compulsory and you are just passing a single value `moduleId` and you are adding it to an `Array` of `ModuleRef` which is totally wrong approach. So, based on what you have said here is the updated code of your code:

```
class Student {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var modulesRefs: [ModuleRef]

    var fullName: String {
        return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, modulesRefs: [ModuleRef]) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.modulesRefs = modulesRefs
    }

    func addModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
        // This will be your updated intializer where you can pass any value you want and other will be taken as default value
        let moduleRef = ModuleRef(moduleId: moduleId)
        self.modulesRefs.insert(moduleRef, at: 0)
    }

    func removeModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
        self.modulesRefs = self.modulesRefs.filter { $0.moduleId != moduleId }
    }
}

class ModuleRef {
    var moduleName: String
    var moduleId: String
    var moduleStartdate: Int

    /// Here you can provide all the default values which you don't want to pass
    init(moduleName: String = "", moduleId: String = "", moduleStartdate: Int = 0) {
        self.moduleName = moduleName
        self.moduleId = moduleId
        self.moduleStartdate = moduleStartdate
    }
}
```

Besides, you can also pass the `nil` value for all making the variable as `optional`. Let me know, if you have any confusion!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert a `ModuleRef` just by passing a `String`.

You need to create an instance for example adding the full name of the student and the UNIX timestamp of the current date

```
func addModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
    let moduleRef = ModuleRef(moduleName: self.fullName, 
                              moduleId: moduleId, 
                              moduleStartDate: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
    self.modulesRefs.insert(moduleRef, at: 0)
}
```

And to remove an object this is more efficient, however the class must conform to `Equatable`

```
func removeModuleId(_ moduleId: String) {
    guard let index = self.modulesRefs.firstIndex(where: {$0.moduleId == moduleId}) else { return }
    self.modulesRefs.remove(at: index)
}
```

I'd even declare `moduleStartDate` as `Date`.

Comment: this is great but  what if I just want the `moduleId` in the `moduleRef` object. How can I do this. I can't just exclude them. Will throw me an error telling me `invalid number of arguments`?

Comment: What exactly are you going to accomplish in the `addModuleId` method? Consider that the `modulesRefs` array contains multiple `ModuleRef` objects which have 3 properties respectively.

Comment: no worries i have set default values to the rest. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to updated your Array type to Any as follows:

```
var modulesRefs: [Any]
```

While access value from array,

```
if let moduleRef = modulesRefs[index] as? ModuleRef {

} else if let str = modulesRefs[index] as? String  {

}
```

Comment: **Do not** use `Any`. For just two different types use a common protocol.

Comment: @vadian this has also confused me why I would any if I'm trynna get the `moduleId` from another class

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do, actually means that there's a flaw in your design.

If you need the functionality to call `student.addModuleId(moduleId)` that means, that `Student` should not hold an array of `ModuleRef`. (Or at least have a mechanism to fetch the whole `ModuleRef` by it's id, and then insert that `ModuleRef` inside the array)

That being said, After figuring out your design to which will it be: `modules: [ModuleRef]` or `moduleIds: [String]`, there are still somethings that you can get use out of:

`Equatable` protocol. If you make `ModuleRef` to conform to `Equatable` protocol,  and check its equality with `id`, then Swift will give you access to `remove(element:_)` method, and you no longer need the `removeModuleId()` method.

Or if all `ModuleId`s are unique, you can implement `Hashable` protocol as well, and use `Set<ModuleRef>` instead of an array to have O(1) remove and insert methods. (right now, remove function, takes O(n) time)

Answer (score -1):

You need to make an array of **`Any`** type..

```
var modulesRefs: [Any] = []
```

You can add element in array like this...

```
modulesRefs.append("Test string")
let obj = ModuleRef(...)
modulesRefs.append(obj)
```

And when you access an element you need to user either `if let` or `guard let` to check its type with safety.

**For eg.**

```
  for obj in modulesRefs {
    if let strType = obj as? String {
       print("\(obj) is string type")
    } else if let moduleRefObj = obj as? ModuleRef {
       print("\(obj) is ModuleRef type")
  }
```

Comment: **Do not** use `Any`. For just two different types use a common protocol.